# programmatic ally update the QnAmaker using C#

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I was able to programmatically add, delete the qna pair using C# and below syntax

new_kb = "{'**add**': { 'qnaList': [{'id': 101001,'answer': '" + answer + "','source': 'Editorial','questions': ['" + Question + "'],'metadata': []}],'urls': []},'delete': {},'update': {}}";

new_kb = "{\"add\":null,\"**delete**\":{\"ids\":[" + id + "],\"sources\":null},\"update\":null}";

I am having an issue with the Update syntax below is what i have tried but no luck

```
new_kb = "{'update': { 'qnaList': [{'id': '" + id + "','answer': '" + ans + "','source': 'Editorial','questions': ['" + qs+ "'],'metadata': []}],'urls': []},'delete': {},'add': {}}";

new_kb = "{\"add\":null,\"update\":{\"ids\":[" + id + "],\"questions\":[" + qs + "],\"answer\":[" + ans+ "],\"sources\":null},\"delete\":null}";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to update your questions/answers of your qna pair , try this :

```
new_kb = "{'update':{'qnaList':[{'id':"+ id +",'answer':'"+ answer + "','questions':{'add':['"+ qs_new + "'],'delete':['"+ qs_old + "']}}]}}";
```

If you have any further concerns , pls feel free to let me know : )

Comment: Hi @spStacker, how's going ? Has the issue been solved ?